# This word is a name. Also a Surname

Tags: word, no-computers

> Starts with a place, ends with a place
>
> Starts with a number, ends with a number
>
> Starts with a surname, ends with a surname
>
> A word to the wise. Only one vowel- used twice.

Can you guess, without searching the web?

Hint

> The numbers are Roman Numerals

Answer (score 6):

Starts with a number, ends with a number

> BAT = 8 ([Zhuang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bat#Zhuang)), MAN = 10000 or myriad ([Vietnamese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/man#Vietnamese))

Starts with a surname, ends with a surname

> Batman is a [mononym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononym)

A word to the wise. Only one vowel- used twice.

> yes indeed, bAtmAn

Starts with a place, ends with a place

> Because Batman begins and ends in Gotham City. And you'll never get away with this, Riddler!

Comment: That is some really deep thought :D

Comment: Wow. Lot of thought indeed. But the title says "Its also a name and a surname. " But +1 for the thought.

Answer (score 5):

I am just going to post my answer because more hints will give it away anyway.

The answer is

> **Marshall** both a name and surname
>
> Starts with a place MARS or MARSH and ends with a place HALL
>
> Starts with a surname MARSH and ends with a surname HALL
>
> Starts with a number M and ends with a number L both Roman Numerals
>
> Uses "a" twice

Comment: I guess, the question is - are there other words that match the requirements?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer might be

> Virgil

Starts with a place,

> Vir - which I think is in Croatia

ends with a place

> Gil

Starts with a number,

> VI - Roman numeral for 6

ends with a number

> L - Roman numeral for 50

Starts with a surname,

> Vir

ends with a surname

> Gil

A word to the wise. Only one vowel- used twice.

> Only uses 'i', twice.

Admittedly it lacks explanation but I've tried not to use the web as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Most of an answer:

> Milling

Starts with a place, ends with a place

> A **mill** is a place, and a common landmark used in street names and other toponyms. In phonology, one of the **places** of articulation in the mouth is the tongue, whose activities are described as **ling**ual.

Starts with a number, ends with a number

> "A **mil**" can be shorthand for a million. The gravitational constant is a number (maybe 6.8...?) and is symbolized by **G**.

Starts with a surname, ends with a surname

> There are surnames all over the place in this one. **Mill**, as in John Stuart, at the beginning. **Ng**, as in Ana, at the end. **Li** in the middle. And **Illing** straddling all 3. (I don't have examples for the latter 2 because [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers).

As for the title - it's definitely a word, and it seems plausible as a surname too, though I can't think of anybody who has it.